# the limit of this series through the definition

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, epsilon-delta

> Show that $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n^2+1}{n+2017}=\infty.$$

I start like that, for every $M>0$ there is an $N>0$, so that for every $n> N$, $$\frac{n^2+1}{n+2017}>M.$$

so how to continue these(according to the definition)? like without any advanced method like the Squeeze theorem and so on?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Please be careful with your writing: is it $\;n+1\;$ or $\;n^2+1\;$ in your expression's numerator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An option:

Let $n >2017.$

Then

$\dfrac{n}{2} = \dfrac{n^2}{2n} \lt \dfrac{n^2+1}{n+2017}.$

It suffices to show that

$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}  (n/2)= \infty.$

Let $M$, real, positive be given.

Archimedes principle:

There is a $N$, positive integer, such that

$N > 2M.$

For $n \ge N$ we have

$n/2 \ge N/2 >M$.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative method, we have $$\small\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n^2+1}{n+2017}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{(n+2017)^2-2\cdot2017n-2017^2+1}{n+2017}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left[n+2017-\frac{2\cdot2017n+2017^2-1}{n+2017}\right]$$ and since $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{2\cdot2017n+2017^2-1}{n+2017}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{2\cdot2017+(2017^2-1)\cdot\frac1n}{1+2017\cdot\frac1n}=\frac{2\cdot2017}1=2\cdot2017$$ using $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1n=0$ along with the Combination Rules for limits, we have that $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n^2+1}{n+2017}=\left[\lim_{n\to\infty}n\right]+2017-2\cdot2017=\left[\lim_{n\to\infty}n\right]-2017=\infty$$

Comment: (1) You answered a question that you yourself edited otherwise (the square in the numerator...?), and (2) The above is **not** according to the definition of limit.

Comment: @DonAntonio OP didn't specifically ask for the definition of a limit. That was what they used. Also gongyuan has already outlined how to continue the OP's way. I'm just writing out an alternative method.

Comment: @DonAntonio And yes I have already reverted back to the original question posed.

Comment: but (n+2017)^2 = n^2 +2*2017*n +2017^2 , where goes thef 2*2017*n. also your technique is good, but what I needed is an answer with M.

Comment: @sam0101 Ah thanks, edited.

Answer (score 0):

We have that

$$\frac{n^2+1}{n+2017}>M \iff n^2-Mn-2016>0$$

which by quadratic formula requires

$$n>\frac{M+\sqrt{M^2+8064}}{2}=k$$

thus it suffices assume $N=\lceil k \rceil $.